# Read binary files without having them buffered in the volume block cache

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, filesystems

Older, now deprecated, macOS file system APIs provided flags to read a file unbuffered.

I seek a modern way to accomplish the same, so that I can read a file's data into memory without it being cached needlessly somewhere else in memory (such as the volume cache).

Reading with `fread` and first calling `setvbuf (fp, NULL, _IONBF, 0)` is not having the desired effect in my tests, for example. I am seeking other low-level functions that let me read into a prepared memory buffer and that let me avoid buffering of the whole data.

**Background**

I am writing a file search program. It reads large amounts of file content (many GBs) that isn't and won't be used by the user otherwise. It would be a waste to have all this data cached in the volume cache as it'll soon get purged by further reads again, anyway. It'll also likely lead to purging file data that's actually in use by the user or system, causing more cache misses.

Therefore, I should be able to tell the system that I do not need the file data cached. The little caching needed for cluster boundaries is not an issue. It's the many large chunks that I read briefly into memory to search it that is not needed to be cached.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

- Use the [`read()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/read.2.html) system call instead of stdio.
- Disable data caching with the `F_NOCACHE` option for [fcntl()](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/fcntl.2.html).

In Swift that would be something like (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
import Foundation

let path = "/path/to/file"
let fd = open(path, O_RDONLY)
fcntl(fd, F_NOCACHE, 1)

var buffer = Data(count: 1024 * 1024)
buffer.withUnsafeMutableBytes { ptr in
    let amount = read(fd, ptr.baseAddress, ptr.count)
}

close(fd)
```

Comment: Do you know that this will avoid filling the volume cache with the read data? Any idea how I could verify it? I.e, is there a function for checking whether a volume's block is in the cache (I have means to figure out the block numbers a file occupies)?

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann: Unfortunately I do not know how to verify it, I can only suggest to compare the performance. It is also discussed in this (old) thread on the Apple Developer Forum: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/25464